# DIMSUM leading to memory issues

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to compute column similarity for big data sets using DIMSUM algorithm

cluster configuration is of 5 nodes of 32GB RAM  with 6 cores each

```
spark-shell --driver-memory 21G --executor-memory 29G
 --conf    "spark.rdd.compress=true"   
--conf "spark.shuffle.memoryFraction=0.5" 
--conf   "spark.storage.memoryFraction=0.3"
 --conf "spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=256m" 
--conf "spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer" 
--num-executors 5   --executor-cores 5
```

DIMSUM code

```
val rows = sc.textFile(filename).map { line =>
val values = line.split(' ').map(_.toDouble)
Vectors.dense(values)
}
val mat = new RowMatrix(rows)


// Compute similar columns with estimation using DIMSUM
val simsEstimate = mat.columnSimilarities(0.2)

val array = simsEstimate.entries.map{case MatrixEntry(row :Long, col:Long, sims:Double) => Array(row, col, sims).mkString(",")}

 val coal = array.coalesce(1, true)
 array.saveAsTextFile("/user/similarity")
```

Data set contains of 3000 rows and 10M columns , It created 601 splits and took 46 min to compute TreeAggregate, when trying to persist the results to file, it is throwing memory allocation issues or thread spilling into disk issue.

Any pointers on how to fix it?

Comment: 10 million columns ?!?

Comment: Yes actually it is 10 million rows with 3000 columns since dimsum gives column similarity I transposed the input matrix to this format

Comment: Hi @tourist, using Kryo serializer will bring performance improvements, but to get the most out of it (and reduce the volume of serialized data which is being spilled) you must register your classes. To make sure all of them are registered you can force it.

Comment: @mauriciojost I've added registerkryoserializer as true, still I'm facing thread spilling issues

Comment: @eliasah 
I'm using 10M columns because it DIMSUM algorithm in spark gives column similarities, so my data set consists of 10M rows with 3000 columns , I transposed the data set and persisted to file and gave input to DIMSUM which is in form of 10M columns and 3000 rows, Is there any issue with this kind of approach

Comment: @tourist okay, but keep in mind that it is not just black or white, i.e. spill or not spill: disk spilling may be something unavoidable for your scenario ( the given algorithm, data, infrastructure and settings). In such case the best you coukd get is few amount of times data get spilled, so I would always keep track of the number of times data gets spilled to see what settings help ;) did some of the changes help decreasing such number so far? could you tell about them?

Comment: @mauriciojost I tried increasing the shuffle size but still it is leading to thread spill issue
INFO collection.ExternalSorter: Thread 177 spilling in-memory map of 1321.0 MB to disk (131 times so far)
I've updated  the complete code.